# M&B: Warband - Do male husbands roam the map?

Tags: mount-and-blade-warband

I'm running a game where I aim to conquer Calradia as a female character, with every faction hostile, and exactly zero vassals, but am thinking about what should I do with marriage. Do husbands stay in a castle after marrying them? In a playthrough like this, are there any other benefits to having a husband than the ability to store items and throw feasts?

Note that I am playing without any mods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, husbands roam the map.
As i was in the same faction as my husband i cannot tell you if you can fight against or with him.(I always fighted alongside with him).

Marriying will increases the relationship with all the relatives of your partner, it also increases your right to rule(but as you are trying to become a sole emperor that doesnt have any advantage).

Comment: Many years later I finally finished my solo conquest of Calradia, and can report that if a husband sours their relationship with you, they indeed defect and fight you as any other lord would. Even with poor relations, upon meeting you're still able to discuss "matters of the household" - managing inventories and such - although holding a feast is off the table.